# Many tables, one, shared structure

Tags: mysql

For example i have 10 databases and they are the same. Only different data.

When i'm making some update in one database table(for example adding new collumn or changing/renaming it), it should affect others tables in all databases.

Can i make some view to make it easier or there is a way to do it automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Trigger, which observe changes in the database structure.

See [MySql trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)